# How can I debug a "BUG IN CLIENT OF LIBPLATFORM: Trying to recursively lock an os_unfair_lock" crash?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, combine

I am writing a simple WKWebView extension that executes some Javascript and return the result as a Future.

```
func runJSFuture(_ js: String) -> Future<Any?, Error> {
    
    Future<Any?, Error> { promise in
        self.evaluateJavaScript(js) { (result: Any?, error: Error?) in
            
            if let errorUnwrapped = error {
                promise(.failure(errorUnwrapped))
                return
            }
                promise(.success(result))
        }
    }
}
```

However, sometimes(consistently at a particular JS, but not all the time, so I figured it's not a problem with the JS itself) I get a crash as follows. I've been debugging and researching for a while and I've checked for implicitly unwrapped vars, force unwrapping. I'm stll unable to find the cause. There is not much useful information on the stack trace as well.

[image: crashing thread]

[image: crash - inline]

[image: crash info]

EDIT :

I've did some poking around converting the future to a PassthroughSubject and I have found where exactly the code in my question crashes. It'd comfort me if one could explain why/ how the crash happens and what I can do to avoid it or if this is a Combine bug.

```
func runJSFuture(_ js: String) -> AnyPublisher<Any?, Error> {
    
    let pts = PassthroughSubject<Any?, Error>()
    
    self.evaluateJavaScript(js) { (result, error) in
        
        if let errorUnwrapped = error {
            
            pts.send(completion: .failure(errorUnwrapped))
            return
        }
        
        pts.send(result)
        //pts.send(completion: .finished) // crashes here
    }
    
    return pts.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

If I comment the line that crashes, the code works fine, but if I understand correctly, the pipeline would be open indefinitely? Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Have you ever resolved this?